# Pin outs and conflicts: Adafruit Voice Bonnet vs TFT Touchscreen

Tags: hardware

Apologies for this simple question, I'm not really a hardware person.

Reading the pinout diagram for the Voice Bonnet here: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-voice-bonnet?view=all it seems (if I understand) that the SPI pins are available?

I want to combine this with a TFT touch screen like this: https://thepihut.com/products/hdmi-4-800x480-ips-touch-screen-gpio that uses SPI for touch. It uses HDMI for display, so no conflict there.

Do I have the the right reading of this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you try and see?

Comment: I'm not anxious to blow anything up, though that probably won't happen

Comment: You are unlikely to damage the Pi by connecting things (provided they are 3.3V). You need to explain what YOU are proposing to connect; the Adafruit article is rather vague & waffly; the TFT has no explicit detail. I would get the 2 going separately first.